# cPanel root login w/ SSH keys

Tags: cpanel, digital-ocean

I currently use SSH keys to access my droplet via CLI. I just setup cPanel but dont have a root password. How do I login initially with SSH keys and no root password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log in with your SSH keys to your `root` account and configure your password by typing `passwd`. Then you can [follow these steps](http://cpanel.net/using_public_key_authentication_for_ssh_and_transfers/) for using Public Key Authentication with cPanel after you've logged in the first time.

Comment: the link isn't working anymore here are other links with same issue and answers were replied https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-can-i-remove-password-after-adding-ssh-key-as-i-was-set-up-originally   https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/where-do-i-find-my-password-after-i-create-a-droplet-with-my-ssh-key